# Failed to fetch in react

Tags: reactjs, mern

I am unable to fetch a url in my MERN application.

**index.js**

```
import {API} from "../../backend";

export const signup = user => {
    return fetch(`${API}/signup`,{
        method:"POST",
        headers:{
            Accept:"application/json",
            "Content-Type":"application/json"
        },
        body:JSON.stringify(user)
    })
    .then(response => {
        return response.json();
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

};
```

**Backend.js**

```
export const API= process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND;
```

**.env**

```
REACT_APP_BACKEND =http://localhost:8000/api
```

**error:-**
[image]

Comment: Hi. Did you try replacing '{API}' with the URL and did it work then?

Comment: @noob_nerd yess mate  , i have already tried that. still it's showing the same error in the console.

Comment: It's strange. Did you try accessing the backend APIs using postman and are they working fine?

Comment: Yess, backend code is aleady tested . All routes are working fine .

Comment: Must be a typo. Please check the urls thoroughly in the .env file and the backend APIs.